# In knex what is the difference between knex().select("id").from("users) and knex("users").select("id")

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron, knex.js

/*I've already established a connection in knex with mysql and i am trying to do a loginForm connected to mysql db and right now i am doing a login check.I was wondering if there is any difference between this: knex().select("id").from("users)
and this: knex("users").select("id")*/

```
function checkLogIn(email, username, password) {
  knex("users").select("id").where({
      email: "email@gmail.com",
      username: "username",
      password: "password",
    })
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you are undecided, you can print the pure sql statement to the console as in the example below:

```js
const query = knex("users").select("id").where("email", userEmail).first()
console.info(query.toString())

// then you can run the query
const result = await query

const otherQuery = knex.select("id").from("users").where("email", userEmail).first()
console.info(otherQuery.toString())

const otherResult = await otherQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no difference between using
`knex().select("id").from("users)` or `knex("users").select("id")`.

`knex().select("id").from("users)` => This is simply method chaining where select and from methods are used. Query at execution time will be `select id from users`

`knex("users").select("id")` => Here, knex knows that the tableName can be passed in param and at execution time will convert the query to `select id from users`